# Using Report Builder - Count Distinct Issue

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have am using a Shared Dataset created by IT and don't access update capabilities.  My report has 4 columns: name, CountDistinct(planid), planid, case.  I only want to see the rows where the CountDistinct(planid) is greater than 1.  Attached is my current output.  I would like my report to only show the 3 rows associated to Carol Haney.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning the results into a table/tablix in SSRS, just open the Tablix Properties and add a Filter on the Filters page to only include records where your `PlanIDCount` column is greater than 1:

[image: TablixPropertiesFilters]